# Always logged in with OpenID, how do I create a password for my account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, password

I always logged in in StackExchange networs sites using my openID.

Now my OpenID provider it's becoming slow to answer, and I'd like to add a password to my account, so I have an alternative login method when OpenID doesn't work.

But actually, can't figure out how to create such password. Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your profile, click on "my logins".  From that modal, select "Add more logins", then proceed to either add another OpenID provider (that's supported), or create a StackExchange username and password.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Initially I though I should do this in Stackexchange, but didn't find any link to create a stackexchange account. Tried again going to Stackoverflow, found it and did it.

Comment: I am probably missing something, but I only have OpenID providers (no option to add password based login). Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue. I can't find an option to create a username/password.