# Giving my Stack Exchange account a password

Tags: discussion, support, login, user-accounts

I am now use Stack Exchange using a Facebook ID. But now I want to close my Facebook account and continue on Stack Exchange. If I create new account, it will lose all my existing accounts in Stack Exchange and reputation points. So I want to give my account a password and use it without a Facebook login. Can I do this?

Comment: [Always logged in with OpenID, how do I create a password for my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184791/21960)

Comment: Just add another login, no need in a new account