# Can't reset password for email credentials when logged in via OpenID

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, password

I log into SE with a Yahoo OpenID, which [I have to stop doing by July](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018).

I apparently also have an email/password login. I don't remember ever creating one (although maybe that's what I used before SO had OpenID support?), and I certainly don't remember the password. <s>And there doesn't seem to be any way to reset my password when logged in via OpenID.</s> And the way to reset my password ([`account-recovery`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery); thanks to Adam Lear) was not discoverable from anywhere I could find. Once you're logged in (via OpenID), there's no links to account recovery anywhere, even on the pages asking me to enter my email and password.

---

If I go to My Logins, I see two entries: `Stack Exchange` and `Yahoo`. The first one has a `change password` link.

So I click `change password`, and I'm taken to a page called `password-reset`, which looks like this:

[image: password-reset screencap]

It requires me to type in my current password. Which I don't know. There's no link anywhere to send a password-reset email, answer a challenge, or do any of the other usual alternatives.

This page could just have a link to `account-recovery`.

---

If I go back to My Logins and instead click `add more logins…`, I'm taken to [a page called `login-add`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add). This page tells me "You are currently logged in as abarnert. Add another way to log in using any of the following services." And then it has this form:

[image]

This is an odd form for adding a login—i.e., registering an email and password—given that there's no confirm-password field.

[I'm pretty sure this is a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307924). But maybe I'm supposed to enter my email and desired password, and I'll be asked to confirm it later? Nope, I try that and click the `Add Login` button, and I get the error `The email or password is incorrect`.

---

I've tried searching around for other ways to reset my password, but everything I can find (links on the above-linked question, instructions [on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184791/always-logged-in-with-openid-how-do-i-create-a-password-for-my-account), etc.)) ultimately takes me to one of the same two pages, where I can't add an email because I already have one, or can't reset my password because I don't know it.

I also get the same behavior if I try it on a different network site instead of SO. (Unless I try it on one I've never visited before, but then it first requires me to login to connect to that site, which I can only do via my Yahoo OpenID because I don't know the password for my other login, which leaves me in the same state.)

Comment: Have you tried [account recovery](/users/account-recovery)?

Comment: @AdamLear I haven't—I was given a link to "account recovery", but it was to the "reset-password" page, not the "account-recovery" page. I'll try that now. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear That seems to have worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it. As I think about it more, we should probably just link to recovery from the password reset page.

Comment: @AdamLear Yes, that's pretty much exactly what I was expecting to find on that page. But meanwhile, it's still at least strange, if not a bug, that the `add-login` page is asking me to enter my existing email and password on a page about adding new logins, as a subform of a form about adding new logins, and with a button labeled `Add Login`. Doesn't that also need something done? And finally, the instructions in the "OpenID Ends" message should probably mention account-recovery for people who have passwords they haven't used in years since switching to OpenID (unless I'm the only one).

Comment: @Adam not sure I follow... we won't be able to use **any** OpenID after July and forced to use only email/password? I thought only Stack Exchange OpenID was going down.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Everything is gonna be dropped except Google, Facebook, and email/password.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Read the link in the first line of the question; they explain everything pretty well there.

Comment: Yes I know, thought Yahoo was in one line with Google and Facebook. Got it now. :)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who has this problem:

- If you want to go back from OpenID to using that old email address, use [account recovery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery).
- If you don't have access to that email address, or want to migrate to a new email address instead, go to [my logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current), remove the Stack Exchange email/password login, then [login-add](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add) a new one.

The first one worked for me, and I can't see why it wouldn't work for anyone else. The second one, I haven't tried, but I've been assured that it would work, and won't do anything wacky like unlink all your network accounts (and support would manually fix it if that did happen).